# jquery check for collision and change path

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a little jquery code, where any number of dots jump around. I want them to not collide on their path to the new coordinate. Is there a way to prevent them from colliding?

My thoughts where using the plugin collision, but I don't know how to use it on moving objects. The documentation also doesn't give a hint.

Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/c0ffi124/anoxLdsb/16

```
function runGame(parameter) {
    document.getElementById("blocks").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('start-button').style.display = 'none';
    let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("block");
    for (div in divs) {
        animateDiv(divs[div]);
    }
};

function makeNewPosition() {

    var height = $(window).height() - 50;
    var width = $(window).width() - 50;

    var newh = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
    var neww = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);

    return [newh, neww];

}

function animateDiv(myclass) {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $(myclass).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, 3000, function() {
        animateDiv(myclass);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the x and y coordinates of the dots.
You can check the distance between 2 dots with pythagorean theorem, and if it's too little, generate new x and y.
If `sqrt(abs((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + abs((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)))` > radius of one dot, the dots are collising.
So you can iterate over all of the possible point pairs, and do this checks.

Comment: Do I implement this function into the animated function, so it constantly checks for collision?

Comment: Yes, I think. But there is an other danger: it only checks positions after the movement. Collision until movement is still possible.

Comment: I found a solution to check in Intervals, but now it gives me the Error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property left of undefined' when I try to get the coordinates.   Code for function: https://codeshare.io/a3E4n1

Comment: $("#block1")  instead of $("block1")

Comment: Thank you, that worked. 

But still get the error: 'app2.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: (x1 - x2) is not a function
    at check_collision'

Comment: Correction: sqrt(abs((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + abs((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)))